# Automatically run commands upon SmarTTY connection

Tags: ssh, unix

Is there a way set up a SmarTTY connection to automatically run a set of commands upon login? For example, once logged in, change to my `$HOME` directory, then start some service i.e.

```
cd $HOME
start servicename
```

I am using SmartTTY version 3.1